# Change input marker

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i change the flashing input marker (the one that looks like this: |) in a textfield? I want it to be a flashing underscore (_) like in the windows cmd instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont't think you can change the browser default blinking cursor..

If you're interested, I found some javascript 'workaround' examples that might get you started in the right direction if you check out the source and tweak a bit.

http://www.burnmind.com/tutorials/typing/

http://shachi.prophp.org/demo.html

http://www.masswerk.at/jsuix/index.html